# How to disappear menu in first page in a better way?

Tags: angular

Angular app has a side-navigation bar (a menu-wrapped UI) like many other apps, done in **AppComponent.html**:

```
<mat-sidenav-container style="height: 100vh;">
  <mat-sidenav>...</mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
        <route-outlet></router-outlet>  
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

and **app-routing.module.ts**

```
[
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'Other', component: OtherComponent },  
  // all above have sidenav menu
]
```

Now, I want to add a Login page **BEFORE** anyone can use it.

1. Login will not have any menu (`sidenav` above).
2. other pages should redirect to `Login` by `AuthGuard`.

So a new Login page is created

LoginComponent.HTML:

```
<p>login works!</p>
<button type="button" (click)="toHome()">To Home</button>
```

LoginComponent.TS:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
toHome(): void
{
  this.myrouter.navigate(['Home']);
}
```

Modified **app-routing.module.ts**:

```
[
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'Login', component: LoginComponent }
]
```

Still menu appears in Login.
[image]

I know I can `*ngIf` in every component to display/disappear the menu, but is there any clean way?

**See StackBlitz** [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aercgm?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can create guard for auth check and bind it to AppComponent:

```js
{ path: '', component: MainComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
{ path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
```

in AuthGuard you can check authentification and redirect to login|singin if user is not authenticated or not redirect if he is authenticated

Comment: Is there an article something explain what `AuthGuard` can do to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: for example: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/06/10/angular-8-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial
and documentation: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Comment: It works out great on protecting authenticated access, but `login` is still wrapped with navigation menu.

Comment: you have 2 ways to fix it:
1) hide the menu via authentication check. it can be solved via same service AuthGuard 
 and ngIf.
2) or the more proper way - create component which will be your root under auth and replace menu from AppComponent to created new (for example MainComponent).

I actualized my answer for second case.

Comment: Same thought!  But 2) is not working as expected, see [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aercgm?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add `guard` to your `routing`.
You need to create a service first for checking if the user is authenticated.
In your `guard` call the service in the function `CanActivate`.
If the user is not authenticated you can redirect with `this.router.navigate`.